# What age were Leah and Rachel when they got married

Tags: midrash, wedding, age, imahot-matriarch-mothers, rachel-imenu

Do we know what age  Leah and Rachel were when yakove married them?

If yes what is it? Source please.

Are there any midrashim on the subject?

Comment: No we do not  know. The Torah doesn't tell us. That doesn't stop Midrashim from speculating.

Comment: Related https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/22576/5120

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The Seder Olam Rabba (ed. Leiner) states ([ch. 2](http://www.sefaria.org/Seder_Olam_Rabbah.2?lang=bi)) that they were twins and were both 22 when they got married:

> נמצאו רחל ולאה נשאו בנות כ"ב כ"ב, שהיו תאומות
>
> Thus, Rachel and Leah were both married at age 22, for they were twins.

According to Rav Chaim Kanievsky's sefer Lamechsa Atik, which gives names and dates and other unspecified details for the Chumash, the Vilna Gaon's version of Seder Olam Rabbah has it that they were both **21**.

Comment: Note that although this is stated in the Midrash, that [doesn't mean we know it to be true](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/53349/belief-in-midrashim/53351#53351).

Comment: +1 Thank you (How old was Yakov?)

Comment: @hazoriz He was 63 when he got the Brachos, spent 14 years at Shem V'ever, and married them seven years after arriving in Charan, which makes him 84.

Comment: For More opinions see http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=46817&st=&pgnum=68

Comment: @hazoriz I haven't looked at that yet, but you are welcome to post it as your own answer.

Comment: @mevaqesh - Although what you have stated concerning midrashim is correct, they _do_ give us an age-old tradition from various Talmudic Sages. That no one can deny.

Comment: @DonielF If Yaakov was 84 and they were 22, modern day marriages that have a gap of 20, 30, even 40 years don't look so bad after all...

Comment: @Yehoshua Yitzchak was 40 and married the 3-year-old Rivkah (Rashi at the beginning of Toldos). Marriage standards in the Torah probably weren't the same as they are today.

Comment: @Yehoshua Worse, I believe there's an opinion that Rachel was actually 12.

Comment: @hazoriz After Avraham, it seems that the other two fathers had a preference for marrying girls much younger than they.

Comment: @DanF what was the age difference by Abraham?

Comment: @DanF the reason might be as simple as the fertility of their wives

Answer (score 6):

[Seder Olam Rabbah 2](https://www.sefaria.org/Seder_Olam_Rabbah.2.2) calculates that they were twins and married Yaakov at 22.

I don’t follow the math, myself. It seems to just throw out there that Rachel was 36 when she died; since Yaakov married her after 7 years working for Lavan, and he left Charan after another 7 years after they got married, plus 6 years after all but Binyamin were born, and Rachel died at the end of the two-year journey back to Yitzchak, they were married for 15 years (I guess she wasn’t exactly 36 when she died).