# When is the Yahrzeit for Leah Imeinu

Tags: death, imahot-matriarch-mothers

I know the yahrzeits for Sara Imeinu, Rochel Imeinu, Miryam Hanevia. But what is the yahrzeit for Leah Imeinu?

Comment: https://www.hidabroot.org/question/237006

Comment: Related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/22576/